# Prove that function $f$ is convex

Tags: convex-analysis

Given convex set $C$ and function $f \colon C \to \mathbb R$, I am told that $f$ is convex if and only if

$$\phi(\lambda) = f(\lambda c + (1-\lambda) c') : [0,1] \to \mathbb R$$

for $c, c' \in C$ is convex on $[0,1]$. I am done with the $\Rightarrow$ implication, but I am struggling with the $\Leftarrow$ one. Any hint would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I’m not sure what your definition of a convex function is.  One definition is that the epigraph of the function is convex.  If you assume that definition, then your iff follows immediately.

Comment: I'm supposed to use the following def: $f(p_1c +p_2 c') \leq p_1f(c) + p_2f(c')$, $c,c'\in C$ and $p_1 + p_2 = 1$.